# SMTP password for RDOPOP3Account not updating

Tags: c#, outlook, smtp, outlook-redemption

I am trying to update and save the password for the `RDOPOP3Account` object that I am using, as the password is implemented as a token, which expires in 5 minutes on the server. 
But whenever I assign the new token to the `RDOPOP3Account.SMTP_Password` property and then run `RDOPOP3Account.Save()` method, the password is reverted back to the old value. 
Any clue about why this might be happening is welcome.

```cs
string Token = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
pop3Account.SMTP_Password = Token;
pop3Account.Save();
```

Comment: What is the relevant snippet of your code?

Comment: I have updated the code with the snippet. pop3Account is class variable and is initialized at the start of the program.

Comment: Try to get rid of the pop3Account.Save() method - it cases the corresponding MAPI object to overwrite the existing data. When you set the SMTP_Password property, it will save the pending changes first, then update the password.

Comment: I have tried doing the same but I keep on encountering the login popup for SMTP whenever the token expires, as the login fails after the token expires.